# nginx getting miss before expire time

Tags: linux, nginx, cache, django

I have an nginx server proxying and caching requests to django backend. The headers when i make a curl to django gunicorn request are the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Date: Mon, 05 Aug 2019 17:30:55 GMT
Connection: close
Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=AV42uqHK4znT5iGHnr4dzaKNUaQmKjw0; expires=Mon, 03-Aug-2020 17:30:55 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
```

I currently ignore the following headers:

```
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Redirect;
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires;
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Limit-Rate;
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Buffering;
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Charset;
proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
proxy_ignore_headers Vary;
```

And for cache i have the following configurations:

```
proxy_buffering on;
proxy_cache STATIC;
proxy_cache_valid any 5m;
add_header X-Proxy-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
add_header X-Proxy-Cached-Date $upstream_http_date;
```

What is happening now is that when i make requests to the server i get the cached content for one minute aproximately and then i get a MISS. I dont care about user sessions so ignoring set-cookie is not a problem.

Where the problem could be? How can i debug this?

Thanks!

Comment: What’s STATIC zone definition?

Answer (score -1):

If everyone have the same problem, my problem was that i was mixing the django app cache folder with the nginx server cache folder. So django was randomly deleting nginx cache files.